# Harmonic number denominator divisibilty proof

Tags: harmonic-numbers

I'm looking for the complete proof (in a textbook preferably) of harmonic number $H_n$ denominator being divisible by all primes $p\in\left[\frac{n+1}{2},n\right]$.

I found one by induction in *Exploring Euler's Constant* by Julian Havil. However, I find it lacking because no reasoning is given why the left part of the interval $\frac{n+1}{2}$ moves too. As I see it, induction step explains the addiction of new primes only.

Comment: Isn't this obvious?  Any prime in that range appears in exactly one denominator, hence can't be cancelled when you add the fractions.

Comment: If you want us to critique the proof, you should show us the proof, or at least the part of it you're calling into question.

Comment: @lulu Of course, but it doesn't stem from the induction as Havil presents it (or I see it). I'm looking proof for the reference purposes and I want everything explained in one place.

P.S. saulspatz The critique of Navil proof is not the goal.

Comment: I don't understand.  The proof is obvious.  If you want the argument to align with some other proof (or sketch), you should provide the other argument.